# Trying and failing to cast a PSObject to Int32 in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Consider:

```
$tabName = "EventsTable"
# Create a table object
$table = New-Object system.Data.DataTable "$tabName"

# Define columns
$col1 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn EventID,([Int32])

$col2 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn EventDate,([datetime])
$col3 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn Instances,([Int32])

# Add the columns
$table.Columns.add($col1)
$table.Columns.add($col2)
$table.Columns.add($col3)

# Enter data in the row
$systemEvents = Get-EventLog `
    -newest 1000 `
    -LogName System `
    -EntryType Information `
    -After (Get-Date).AddDays(-3);

for ($i=0; $i -lt 1; $i++) { #$systemEvents.Count
    # Create a row
    $row = $table.NewRow()
    $row.EventID = $systemEvents.Get($i).EventID
}
```

The penultimate line of code fails due to an "Exception setting

> ```
>  "EventID":
>  "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Management.Automation.PSObject' to
>  type 'System.IConvertible'.Couldn't store <2010> in EventID Column.
>  Expected type is Int32."
> ```

However if I change this line to...

`$systemEvents.Get($i).EventID.GetType()`

The output is Int32.

If EventID is a [PSObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psobject), how do I get the Int32 out of it? If EventID is an Int32 then what is PowerShell complaining about?

Comment: Just add `[int]` or `[int32]`in front: `$row.EventID = [int]$systemEvents.Get($i).EventID`

Comment: Have managed to get around the issue by converting EventID.ToString(). Edit: Actually have gone with what iRon said. Thanks!

Comment: What is the intent of your for loop?  It looks like it's only executed once.

Comment: Your probably reinventing the wheel: have a look at: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/4208a159-a52e-4b99-83d4-8048468d29dd, meaning a simply command like this: `$DataTable = get-eventlog -newest 1000 -LogName System -EntryType Information -After (Get-Date).AddDays(-3) | Out-DataTable`  will probably work for you.

Answer (score 3):

As [iRon said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47727369/powershell-trying-and-failing-to-cast-a-psobject-to-int32#comment82415740_47727369), just add [int] or [int32] in front:

```
$row.EventID = [int]$systemEvents.Get($i).EventID
```